# Function doesn't recognize Yaml nested struct

Tags: go, struct

I have the following struct YAML:

```
type YamlConfig struct {
    Items struct {
        RiskyRoles []struct {
            Name string `yaml:"name"`
            Rules []struct{
                Verbs []string `yaml:"verbs"`
                ResourceOperator string `yaml:"resourcesOperator"`
                Resources []string `yaml:"resources"`
            }
        } `yaml:"RiskyRoles"`
    } `yaml:"Items"`
}
```

I have a function that parse a YAML file to an object and then I want to send the `Rules` struct object  to a function named `DoingStuff(..)`:

```
yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("actionItems.yaml")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error reading YAML file: %s\n", err)
} else{
    var yamlConfig YamlConfig
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &yamlConfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error parsing YAML file: %s\n", err)
    }

    for _, yamlRole := range yamlConfig.Items.RiskyRoles{
       DoingStuff(yamlRole.Rules)
    }
}
```

But inside the function `DoingStuff`, the struct object `Rules` is not recognized:

```
func DoingStuff(yamlRules []struct{}) {
  // Not recognize ****
  for _, rule := range yamlRules {
      fmt.Print(rule.ResourceOperator)
  }
}
```

How can I convert it to:

```
Rules []struct{
    Verbs []string `yaml:"verbs"`
    ResourceOperator string `yaml:"resourcesOperator"`
    Resources []string `yaml:"resources"`
}
```

Should I re-declare this struct again?
Or cast using interfaces ?

**EDIT:**

I added new struct and used it inside the `YamlConfig` struct but the parse failed to parse the Rules:

```
type RulesStruct struct {
    Rules []struct{
        Verbs []string `yaml:"verbs"`
        ResourceOperator string `yaml:"resourcesOperator"`
        Resources []string `yaml:"resources"`
    }
}
type YamlConfig struct {
    Items struct {
        RiskyRoles []struct {
            Name string `yaml:"name"`
            Message string `yaml:"message"`
            Priority string `yaml:"priority"`
            Rules []RulesStruct
        } `yaml:"RiskyRoles"`
    } `yaml:"Items"`
}
```

Comment: Declare a named struct and use that in the yaml config as well as the function argument. Note that, *"the struct object `Rules` is not recognized"* is because the type `[]struct{}` and the type of the `Rules` field is not one and the same, clearly.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't parse the rules, maybe I didn't do it correctly? See my edits.

Comment: Hard to tell why without seeing the yaml file. Note however that your `Rules []RulesStruct` field is missing a yaml tag and also the structure is different from the previous anonymous version of the `Rules` field.

Comment: OK I managed to do it, found my problem, thanks ! I will publish an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @mkporiva help, I changed the structs like that:

```
type RulesStruct struct {

    Verbs []string `yaml:"verbs"`
    ResourceOperator string `yaml:"resourcesOperator"`
    Resources []string `yaml:"resources"`

}

type YamlConfig struct {
    Items struct {
        RiskyRoles []struct {
            Name string `yaml:"name"`
            Message string `yaml:"message"`
            Priority string `yaml:"priority"`
            Rules []RulesStruct
        } `yaml:"RiskyRoles"`
    } `yaml:"Items"`
}
```

Now it works fine.